# If statement inside array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array each array has a value.

Here is an example of this:

```
$sales_payload = array(
    'organization_id' => $organization_id,
    'contact_id' => $contact_id,
    'status' => 'Open',
    'subject' => $_product->post_title." ".str_replace($strToRemove, "", $_POST['billing_myfield12']),
    'start_date' => date("Y-m-d"), // set start date on today
    'expected_closing_date' => date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date("Y-m-d")."+ 14 days")), // set expected closing date 2 weeks from now
    'chance_to_score' => '10%',
    'expected_revenue' => 0, //set the expected revenue
    'note' => $_POST['order_comments'],

    'progress' => array(
    'id'=>'salesprogress:200a53bf6d2bbbfe' //fill a valid salesprogress id to set proper sales progress 
    ),

    "custom_fields"=> [[ 
    if(strpos($_POST['billing_myfield13'], 'ja') !== false) { [["actief_in_duitsland"=>1]] }
    ]]
);
```

I am now trying to fill a certain array in my code this one:

```
"custom_fields"=>  [["actief_in_duitsland"=>1]]
```

This works. Only thing is  I want the value to be =>1 on a certain condition.
This condition is if a certain POST request contains a certain string then make the value `=> 1`

I tried this :

```
"custom_fields"=> [[ 
if(strpos($_POST['billing_myfield13'], 'ja') !== false) { [["actief_in_duitsland"=>1]] }
]]
```

So

```
if(strpos($_POST['billing_myfield13'], 'ja') !== false) { [["actief_in_duitsland"=>1]] }
```

If the `$_POST['billing_myfield13']` contains the word 'ja'

then `[["actief_in_duitsland"=>1]]`

Comment: No, you can't have `if` statements inside array definitions. You can however use ternarys, though whether those are appropriate is another matter.

Comment: or you could just assign the boolean result of your comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ternary conditions, which is a shortcut for an `if` statement. Here is an example of how ternary conditions works :

A regular if would be written like this :

```
if( "mycondition" == 1 )
{
    $boolean = true;
}
else {
    $boolean = false;
}
```

The equivalent of this statement with ternary condition would be written like below :

```
$boolean = ( "mycondition" == 1 ) ? true : false;
```

You might want to use this shortcut to instanciate your array like following :

```
$sales_payload = [
    // ...
    'custom_fields' => ( strpos($_POST['billing_myfield13'], 'ja') !== false ) ? [['actief_duitsland' => 1]] : [['actief_duitsland' => '???']],
    // ...
];
```

**Warning**

You should also define a `else` value for this statement.

Answer (score 2):

If statement inside the array shouldn't work, you can try following code

```
    $actief_in_duitsland = (strpos($_POST['billing_myfield13'], 'ja') !== false)  ? 1 : 0;

$sales_payload = array(
    'organization_id' => $organization_id,
    'contact_id' => $contact_id,
    'status' => 'Open',
    'subject' => $_product->post_title." ".str_replace($strToRemove, "", $_POST['billing_myfield12']),
    'start_date' => date("Y-m-d"), // set start date on today
    'expected_closing_date' => date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date("Y-m-d")."+ 14 days")), // set expected closing date 2 weeks from now
    'chance_to_score' => '10%',
    'expected_revenue' => 0, //set the expected revenue
    'note' => $_POST['order_comments'],

    'progress' => array(
    'id'=>'salesprogress:200a53bf6d2bbbfe' //fill a valid salesprogress id to set proper sales progress 
    ),

    "custom_fields"=> [['actief_in_duitsland' => $actief_in_duitsland]]
);
```